# LibGDX How you would put cloth on a model character in run time?

Tags: libgdx

Im trying to make an outfit changer in libGDX. I have this naked character model and a few accessories models. The naked model has bones and animations like run, walk, etc...

I want the user to be able to change clothes, hair or put accessories. So I figured I make these models separate.

The problem is I have no clue how to parent these accessories to the bones in runtime.
So I might be looking for something like blender option `Parent->Armature Deform->Automatic weights` but in libGDX runtime.

My question is:

1. How to parent a model to the base model bones in runtime?

Note that I'm open to suggestions on how to archive this. It's just the only way I could think of doing it.

Comment: It's hard to help you because we don`t see any of your code. Your question is pretty broad. Are you using Spine? You could read here: http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php/topic,31686

Comment: @LOLWTFasdasdasdad Im not using spine, im using 3d models, `Model` class and `ModelInstance` class from libgdx